# How to detect if value exists in an array

Tags: angularjs, arrays, sorting, typescript

I have this array :

```
[
  {praticien: "place_1509136116761", H0709: false, H0911: false, H1113: false, H1315: false},
  {praticien: "place_1509136116773", H0709: false, H0911: false, H1113: false, H1315: false},
  {praticien: "place_1509136116699", H0709: true, H0911: false, H1113: false, H1315: false},
  {praticien: "place_1509136116734", H0709: false, H0911: true, H1113: true, H1315: false}
]
```

I need a way to calcul how many time the H0709 - H0911 - H1113 - H1315 contains the value "TRUE".

Any help ?

Comment: What have you tried so far? Have you tried forEach, for..of, etc.,

Comment: Hi have tried indexOf

Comment: Show your code, please.

Comment: What exactly is the expected result?

Comment: I need to know if at least one  "Praticien" have one of these keys (H0709, H0911, etc) with the value true.

Comment: I already tried with this.activePraticiens.indexOf('H0709: true"), etc..

Comment: @RunfastWebmaster This does not explain what the expected result should be. Is it `true`, or `2`, or `3`, or `[0,0,1,2]`, or maybe something else? Please be specific when asking questions.

Comment: The result should be 1, 2, 3 4 or 0

Comment: @RunfastWebmaster Please give the *exact* result you expect for the example you gave. Still not sure whether you expect `2` or `3` (or an array with four numbers?) in this case.

Comment: is it AND or OR? Do u need to have   all H0709 - H0911 - H1113 - H1315 true at the same time? or even one of them is enough to count?

Comment: No code is provided. We don't code for u

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `array#reduce` to loop through your data array and use `array#filter` to find out all key in `param` which have true value.

```js
const data = [{praticien: "place_1509136116761", H0709: false, H0911: false, H1113: false, H1315: false},{praticien: "place_1509136116773", H0709: false, H0911: false, H1113: false, H1315: false},{praticien: "place_1509136116699", H0709: true, H0911: false, H1113: false, H1315: false},{praticien: "place_1509136116734", H0709: false, H0911: true, H1113: true, H1315: false}],
      keys =['H0709', 'H0911', 'H1113', 'H1315'];

const result = data.reduce((sum,o) => {
  sum += keys.filter(k => o[k]).length;
  return sum;
},0)

console.log(result);
```

To get the count of all keys with `true` value, you can use `array#reduce` and `array#forEach`. Inside the `array#foreach`, check if the key has true value and add that key and count.

```js
const data = [{praticien: "place_1509136116761", H0709: false, H0911: false, H1113: false, H1315: false},{praticien: "place_1509136116773", H0709: false, H0911: false, H1113: false, H1315: false},{praticien: "place_1509136116699", H0709: true, H0911: false, H1113: false, H1315: false},{praticien: "place_1509136116734", H0709: false, H0911: true, H1113: true, H1315: false}];

const result = data.reduce((res,o) => {
  Object
    .keys(o)
    .forEach(k => {
      if(o[k] === true) 
        res[k] = (res[k] || 0) + 1 ;
    });
  return res;
},{});

console.log(result);
```

Comment: No, cos I need to know each time true was count and for wich key : H0709 or H0911, etc..

Comment: Do want the true count of each key?

Comment: Yes, thats where I'm stuuck.

Comment: Check the updated solution. It will only display the key which have true value.

Comment: Great !!!!! 
Thank you Hassan !

Answer (score 1):

```
var arr = [{praticien: "place_1509136116761", H0709: false, H0911: false, H1113: false, H1315: false}, {praticien: "place_1509136116773", H0709: false, H0911: false, H1113: false, H1315: false}, {praticien: "place_1509136116699", H0709: true, H0911: false, H1113: false, H1315: false}, {praticien: "place_1509136116734", H0709: false, H0911: true, H1113: true, H1315: false}]

var result = {
    true: 0,
  false: 0
}

arr.forEach(function(obj){ // iterates objects in array
  for (prop in obj ){ // iterates properties in object (only those of object not inherited)
    if (obj.hasOwnProperty(prop)) {
        if (obj[prop]) result.true++;
      else result.false++;
    }
  }
});

console.log(result);
```

This should count how many true and falses are in all your objects. Only thing it doesn't check if property is named Hsomething. If you need that you can add additional condition in `if (obj.hasOwnProperty(prop))` part.

Here is demo: [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/tx5btuc3/)

**EDIT: Only property names starting with 'H' are taken into account.**

Line that has changed in above code:

```
if (obj.hasOwnProperty(prop) && prop[0] === 'H') {
```

New demo can be found at:
[new fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/tx5btuc3/1/)

NOTE: `console.log` has been added to list properties taken into account. For production comment it out or remove it.

Comment: Let me check.. I test it now

Comment: Really good ! But now if have to add the condition.

Comment: I will accept your answer when I will make it work with the name of the Key (H0709, H0911, etc..)

Comment: Are those  the only properties that start with H?

Comment: Yes Dante. True count for each key

Comment: I already did the modification. It counts both true and false but you can pick only true from the end result ;)

Answer (score 1):

You may just try filter to get the objects with the values you expect

```
function predicate(object) {
  return object[H0709];
}

var objectsWithH0709AsTrue = myArray.filter(predicate);
var howManyTimesH0709IsTrue = objectsWithH0709AsTrue.length;
```

Yet there are many ways to do this. Take a look at lodash' some.

Comment: A lib instead 5 lines of simple code? This is an overkill..

Comment: It is up to the persona that encounters the situation to take the decision, so that the context counts.

Answer (score 0):

```
                var data = [
                  {
                    praticien: "place_1509136116761",
                    H0709: false,
                    H0911: false,
                    H1113: false,
                    H1315: false
                  },
                  {
                    praticien: "place_1509136116773",
                    H0709: false,
                    H0911: false,
                    H1113: false,
                    H1315: false
                  },
                  {
                    praticien: "place_1509136116699",
                    H0709: true,
                    H0911: false,
                    H1113: false,
                    H1315: false
                  },
                  {
                    praticien: "place_1509136116734",
                    H0709: false,
                    H0911: true,
                    H1113: true,
                    H1315: false
                  }
                ]
            var result = { H0709: 0,H0911: 0,H1113: 0,H1315: 0};
                angular.forEach(data, function(obj){
                   if(obj.H0709){
                      result[H0709] = result[H0709]++;
                   }
                   if(obj.H0911){
                      result[H0911] = result[H0709]++;
                   }
                   if(obj.H1113){
                      result[H1113] = result[H0709]++;
                   }
                   if(obj.H1315){
                      result[H1315] = result[H0709]++;
                   }
                });
```

result will be { H0709: 1, H0911: 1, H1113: 1, H1315: 0 }

which means that H0709, H0911 and H1113 are only one time **TRUE** whereas H1315 is 0 times.